# Failed to resolve com.android.support:support-compat:25.4.0

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library

I am trying to include [this](https://github.com/wasabeef/recyclerview-animators/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=compile%20%27com.android.support%3Asupport-core-ui%3A25.4.0%27) library to my project by adding

```
compile 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:2.2.7'
```

to the dependencies. When the graddle sync happens an error produced like below

> Failed to resolve com.android.support:support-recycleriew-v7:25.4.0
>
> Failed to resolve com.android.support:support-compat:25.4.0
>
> Failed to resolve com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.4.0

The graddle dependencies looks like

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.5'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.8.5'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.8.5'
compile 'com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-compat:25.4.0'
compile 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:2.2.7'

}
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
Failed to resolve com.android.support:support-recycleview:25.4.0
```

There is no library by that name. There is `com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.4.0`.

```
Failed to resolve com.android.support:support-compat:25.4.0
Failed to resolve com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.4.0
```

These are in the new Google Maven repo. Add `maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }` to your `repositories` closure, as shown in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html#add-library).

Comment: it was recyclerview-v7:25.4.0. That was a typing error. and it works now. thanks.